# RootViewController doesn't respond when set in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an iOS application which needs to be launched with different rootViewControllers (for example if the user had already registered, or if it started after a local notification), and these viewControllers are in different storyboards. I thought one way to do this, is to leave the Main interface field blank in the Deployment info, and configure the rootViewController manually.

I set the rootViewController in my application delegate class:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    IDOptionsViewController *mainViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"options"];
    self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

When I launch the application, the rootViewController appears, but it does not respond to any user interaction (I tested the viewController, it works fine other places).

I'm new to Objective-C and iOS, so I'm not sure I even understand storyboards correctly.

I'm using iOS SDK 7.1, Xcode 5.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: First: you can define which storyboard is the default one in your target. Then you don't need all these code. Second: are you sure you don't override existing UIWindow?

Comment: Can you explain which is the behavior you expect from your app?... so we can give you a better solution?

Comment: @Szu, the window property is nil at the beginning of the method. I also edited my question with some additional information to explain my problem better.

Comment: @Marcio Romero Patrnogic I edited my question, explaining my problem more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In may case the root `UIViewController` called

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents]
```

So, make sure user interaction events are enabled by calling `[UIApplication sharedApplication].isIgnoringInteractionEvents]`. To enable user interaction events call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents]`.