# Switching RootViewController programmatically disables touch

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm loading a view controller that has a button. This button calls the following code:

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).showMainFlow()
```

`showMainFlow()` in the app delegate looks like this:

```
func showMainFlow(){
        self.window?.rootViewController = 
        UINavigationController(rootViewController: vcCustom())
    }
```

This is supposed to set the root view controller to vcCustom when they press the button.. and it does. Except, touches are disabled in vcCustom. That view has a collectionView and I can't scroll in it at all... Any root view controller that I set from my button programatically has touches disabled.

It only works if I set the `rootViewController` in the `appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to `vcCustom` but I can't do this because the user has to login first.

Why is this happening? I've done this exact thing before and had no issues

Comment: Have you tried calling `makeKeyAndVisible` on the `window`?

Comment: @nathan yeah. It's mind boggling because I do this exact thing in my other apps and it works fine... It's literally just switching the rootViewController when the user logs in or if they're logged in when the app starts. Currently-It loads the ViewController I want to show but all touches are disabled... I'm going to look into if it could have anything to do with the new Xcode or swift... wtf

Comment: My thought would be that you have some clear view on top of everything which is intercepting the touches. You should try using the Visual View Hierarchy Debugger to see if there's anything over your view controller.

Comment: @nathan I tried that but it looked fine. Basically when I'm at the view where all touches are disabled, it's UIWindow -> UILayoutContainerView -> UINavigationTransitionerView -> UIViewControllerWrapper ... not really sure if anything there speaks to you. Also, if it was that then I think I would have easily found it because it works when I set the RootViewController from the beginning just not after the app is already running.

Comment: Does anything here help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/25115134/6658553

Comment: @nathan smh.... I have a custom activity indicator that's defined in a helper class. When the user clicks login.. I current have all the code commented except startActivityIndicator and the code that switches the root view controller. Turns out my activity indicator calls beginIgnoringInteractionEvents... HAHA Thanks

Comment: Great. I summed up the result in an answer so others don't have to dig through all of our comments.

Comment: @nathan appreciate it. take care

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue (discovered in the comments on the question) was that an activity indicator was calling `beginIgnoringInteractionEvents`.

If anyone else has this issue in the future, it's worth searching the project for this string or anything similar which may disable touch events from occurring.